# Java 8 CompletedFuture and ThreadLocalRandom

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8, thread-local, completable-future

I'm working exercises from the book "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann.

> Write a method
>
> ```
> public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> repeat(
>          Supplier<T> action, Predicate<T> until)
> ```
>
> that asynchronously repeats the action until it produces a value that
>   is accepted by the `until` function, which should also run
>   asynchronously. Test with a function that reads a
>   `java.net.PasswordAuthentication` from the console, and a function
>   that simulates a validity check by sleeping for a second and then
>   checking that the password is "secret".

I came up with the following code but the random password generation strategy seems to be failing me. All threads constantly pick the same password, which seems very odd.

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> repeat(final Supplier<T> action, final Predicate<T> until) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> futureAction = supplyAsync(action);
    final boolean isMatchFound = futureAction.thenApplyAsync(until::test).join();

    final T suppliedValue = getSuppliedValue(futureAction);

    if (isMatchFound) {
        LOGGER.info("Got a match for value {}.", suppliedValue);

        return futureAction;
    }

    return repeat(() -> suppliedValue, until);
}

private static <T> T getSuppliedValue(final CompletableFuture<T> futureAction) {
    try {
        return futureAction.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

The test case:

```
@Test
public void testRepeat() {
    Supplier<PasswordAuthentication> action = () -> {
        final String[] passwordVault = new String[] { "password", "secret",
            "secretPassword" };

        final int len = passwordVault.length;

        return new PasswordAuthentication("mickeyMouse",
            passwordVault[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(len)].toCharArray());
    };
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    Predicate<PasswordAuthentication> until = passwordAuth -> {
        try {
            currentThread().sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fail(e.getMessage());
        }

        final String password = String.valueOf(passwordAuth.getPassword());

        LOGGER.info("Received password: {}.", password);

        return password.equals("secret");
    };

    repeat(action, until);
}
```

One run, see how oddly the same password is picked:

> 2015-01-09 15:41:33.350 [Thread-1] [INFO ]
>   n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Received password:
>   secretPassword. 2015-01-09 15:41:34.371 [Thread-3] [INFO ]
>   n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Received password:
>   secretPassword. 2015-01-09 15:41:35.442 [Thread-5] [INFO ]
>   n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Received password:
>   secretPassword. 2015-01-09 15:41:36.443 [Thread-7] [INFO ]
>   n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Received password:
>   secretPassword. 2015-01-09 15:41:37.451 [Thread-9] [INFO ]
>   n.a.j.j.c.PracticeQuestionsCh6Test - Received password:
>   secretPassword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug. The supplier that I created was returning the same value everytime. Following is the corrected code. One question though: why does the compiler force the cast?

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> repeat(final Supplier<T> action,
        final Predicate<T> until) {
    final CompletableFuture<T> futureAction = supplyAsync(action);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    CompletableFuture<T> future = (CompletableFuture<T>) futureAction
        .thenApplyAsync(until::test).thenApply(
            isMatchFound -> isMatchFound ? futureAction : repeat(action, until));

    future.join();

    return future;

}
```

Comment: Because the code, as you have written, creates a `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>>` rather than `CompletableFuture<T>`. The last call in your chain should be [`thenComposeAsync`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenComposeAsync-java.util.function.Function-) rather than `thenApply`. But your code is still asynchronous but not parallel as every step is triggered *after* the previous stage completed. Therefore, if you want parallel execution you should use `Stream.generate(action).parallel().filter(until).findFirst()`…

Comment: @Holger Yes, not every step is async and the problem statement doesn't ask for that. It just requires that `until` be async from `action`, which I intended to achieve using `thenApplyAsync` on `until`.
Why do you think `thenComposeAsync` is a better choice than `thenApply` as the final step in the pipeline? I don't need the last step to be async so even if I used compose, I'd go for `thenCompose`, but I'm curious why would you choose compose over apply.

Comment: @Holger If I use compose, then the return type'd be `CompletableFuture<T>` instead of `<CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>>`. That'd also explain the cast. However, reading the Javadoc, it seems that compose accepts the **previous stage** as the argument, not the previous stage's **result**. However, that doesn't seem to be happening in practice - it seems to be receiving the boolean result and not a `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`. _"Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage as the argument to the supplied function."_

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going down a needlessly complicated path.  Since the supply-test-supply-test-supply-test sequence is sequential, initial `supplyAsync` is all you need.  There's no reason to do async within async.

Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> repeat(final Supplier<T> action,
        final Predicate<T> until) {

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
        Stream.generate(action)
                .filter(until)
                .findFirst()
                .get()
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think this meets the requirement that the `until` function should also run asynchronously. See the problem statement in my post above.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar: [`Stream.parallel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--)…